# use Windows path variable in MobaXterm

Tags: mobaxterm

How can I use the Windows path in MobaXterm?

I enjoy using MobaXterm for bash commands in windows.  But I dislike that I need to change directories to run many executables.

[The MobaXterm documentation mentions using the windows path](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#3_2_4) but doesn't describe how to do it.

Comment: I suppose I can just create sym links for frequently used executables.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the documentation, this mention is in the "Terminal tab settings" section, so you will find this option in the "Terminal" tab.

Go to MobaXterm global settings window, then click on the "Terminal" tab and check the "Use Windows PATH environment". Note that if you are using a session, you will have to do the same in this session: edit your session, then go to the "Terminal settings" tab and check the "Use Windows PATH" option.

Comment: if you change the windows path (for instance if you install software), you have to restart mobaxterm for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I am using MobaXterm 10.4 and this feature seams to be buggy. I mark the "Use Windows PATH", I restart MobaXterm; yet the PATH in regular CMD is different than the PATH in MobaXterm cmd tab